# How to integrate $\int_a^t e^{-(x^2)}2x dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I know the integral from $a$ to $t$ for $2x$ is $x^t-x^a$. However, I am stumped on the $e^{-(x^2)}$ part.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a $u$ substitution.  Let $u=x^2$, then $du=2xdx$ and you are there.  It is not true that $\int f(x)g(x)dx=\left(\int f(x)dx \right)\left(\int g(x)dx\right)$

By the way, $\int_a^t 2xdx=\left.x^2\right|_a^t=t^2-a^2$

Comment: We have not been taught the substitution method.

Comment: @koloa:  In that case, you will just have to take the derivative of $e^{-(x^2)}$ and see what happens.

Comment: ahhh yes...take the derivative of (e)^(-(x)^(2))2x and use that for f(t) - f(a). Thank you